# Make child div fit its content while its parent has scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

I need to make the `.child` div wide as its content, but at the same time, the `.child` div is child of an element with horizontal scrollbars.

Is there a way without have to use `fit-content` (fit/min/max) and without javascript?

Demo:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/ZQOjZj

I've this CSS:

```
.parent
  width: 100px
  overflow: auto
  background: yellow

  .child
    background: cyan
    height: 20px
    white-space: nowrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because the `.child` element is a block-level element with a default width of `100%`. This results in the `.child` element having the same width as the parent element.

You could add `display: inline-block` to the `.child` element. In doing so, it will have a ["shrink-to-fit" width](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#lsquo) and take the width dimensions of the text.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZzBrb)

```
.parent .child {
    background: #0ff;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively, setting the `display` to `table` would have a similar affect as well.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKeBMX)

```
.parent .child {
    background: #0ff;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: choosing your answer because you have added the link to the spec and added the alternative `table` method! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just display `.child` `inline-block`:

(Stylus)

```
  .child
    background: cyan
    height: 20px
    white-space: nowrap
    display:inline-block;
```

(Compiled)

```
.parent .child {
  background: #0ff;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Inline and inline-block elements [shrink to fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#shrink-to-fit) their content, unless a width or height is set.

### [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/qbNyGz)

Or, a working snippet:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ff0;
}
.parent .child {
  background: #0ff;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child child child child</div>
</div>
```